# should I use SQLite + MySQL to provide a high performance along with data storage?

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite

I am new to databases and trying to come up with a solution that will provide me with performance as well as data storage capabilities.

So here is my situation:

1. I have a continuos real-time data flow at rate of a few hundred milliseconds. I want to storage these data as well as retrieving those data in future.

Here is my plan:

1. use a central data server that are running MySQL to store those data. The central server will be on an internal network with Gigabyte ethernet.
2. A proxy client machine running SQLite. The client will be responsible for receiving the data as well as storing them locally(SQLite) and remotely (Central Database running MySQL)
3. Other slave clients, running SQLite, could retrieve data from Central Database and store them into their own local SQLite. 
   (Slave Clients and central database doesn't need to be sync with real-time data in real-time. But should sync up once in a while - periodically)

My Reason behind this is that SQLite should be a lot of faster than a networked Central Database in this situation. I am hoping storing the data locally in real-time and then periodically pushing those data into remote database won't cause too much performance suffer.

I am wondering if this would satisfy my requirement and if there is any design that can achieve this with better performance and data integrity? (Expandability is also a consideration is both performance and integrity are the same)

The database interface will be written in C++, i already found all the necessary interfaces for SQLite and MySQL, now just need to nail down the design part.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think at thirst it's better to use one central MySQL server and check the system's bandwidth.  On clients you can create a class which provides unified interface to your storage. First it will buffer and send the data to remote MySQL. If performance isn't good enough it's time to optimize; use SQLite on your clients and write new implementation of storage interface without changing other client logic.
You don't realy know what to expect from any design. We should avoid premature optimization.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize